# Splitting hierarchical codes into parent items (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

source cell: `CCA, BF`
result cell: `C, CC, CCA, B, BF`

`CCA` is a complex code relating to a hierarchy. It means, `CCA` is child of `CC`, which is child of `C`. So, the formula should split into all parents (C and `CC`) and keep the child (`CCA`) -- and do this for a concatenated list of strings. The current maximum of levels is four (`ABCD`) but might be more in the future.

I have no clue how to create a formula for this.

It's connected to the research data being part of https://raramagnetica.vercel.app/vikus/vismag/

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User five times.

Answer (score 0):

Try `split()` and `join()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( join( ", ", unique( flatten( transpose( left( split(A2, ", ", true, true), sequence( max( len( split(A2, ", ", true, true) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )`